# Run loop for a text-based adventure game

Tags: python, adventure-game

I am programming a graphical text adventure using python. The game is playable, but I am not sure whether the code is well-suited for newcomers (code smells / quirks / general readability).

Here's the main script:

```
import time
import sys

import printer
from rooms import *
from _player import Player

VER = 0.01

SCENES = {0 : Lobby(),
          1 : LivingRoom(),
          2 : Bathroom()}

player = Player()

def run(start_at=None):
    """Starts the game"""

    if not start_at:
        scene = SCENES[0]
    else:
        scene = SCENES[start_at]
    scene.init_player(player)
    while 1:
        new_scene = scene.run()
        if new_scene != None:
            scene = SCENES[new_scene]
            scene.init_player(player)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Consider breaking your code into smaller, digestible posts. Nobody is likely to review your entire project for free. Try with a single module, and include as much context/explanation as possible. I have an entire VBE add-in being peer reviewed on this site, spanning over 30 questions. Ask one, wait for feedback, improve your code base, then ask another.

Comment: [Relevant meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/607/23788)

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: phew, sorry... still learning how this works here. thx

Answer (score 7):

Avoid wildcard imports. Import from `rooms` just what you need, named explicitly.

`while 1` is an unnatural way of writing `while True`

Don't use `!=` or `==` with `None`. Use `is not None` and `is None`.

The `scene.run` call that returns another scene object is not very intuitive. Functions are best named after what they do and/or what they return. In this example "run" is a pretty vague term, it could mean anything. If it transitions the game state to the next scene, I think `scene.next_scene` would be more intuitive.

Do you really need `SCENES` ? How about just passing around `scene` instances? This approach using a global dictionary of index to instance mappings seems fishy.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. Let's work that through bit by bit: Wildcard imports. I still use them quite often... If I have an "objects.py" module containing 20 object classes, how can I make them accessible without having to type "from objects import bla, bli, blu, blo, foo, bar, ..." ? When that useless typing begins, I put a *, make sure there are no clashes and that's it...

Comment: @DonPolettone `from foo import bar.*` implies that you are importing _every class_ in `bar`, even those you don't need. It's better to instead import only what you need, and leave the rest alone (so they are not put in memory, and things like that). A lot of IDEs handle that for you, in some way or another, and save you a lot of typing.

Comment: I'd say running a scene is pretty intuitive

Comment: It looks like there will eventually be many rooms. I think a wildcard import is reasonable here, as long as there is _only one_ wildcard import in this file. Listing everything explicitly just adds unnecessary verbosity.

Comment: @michaelsnowden I agree that was a bit weak. I rewrote that paragraph

Comment: When you need many objects from a package, another option is to import the entire package, possibly with a conveniently shorter alias

Answer (score 6):

- You shouldn't store the version of your game in a variable named `VER`. Preferably, you should use `__version__`. At the top of your file, put this. You can also use `__author__` to describe the project with your name as well.

---

```
__version__ = "0.01"
__author__ = "My name"
...
```

---

- The function `run` should be renamed to `main`, just to stay consistent.
- The docstring for `run` should have more info than just `"""Starts the game"""`. Preferably, it should be fleshed out with useful information about `run`, like the arguments, and what it does.
- The way you've formatted your dictionaries is, odd. Dictionaries, list, and tuples can look like this. While your current style doesn't violate PEP8. I find this style easier to read.

---

```
SCENES = {
    0: Lobby(),
    1: LivingRoom(),
    2: Bathroom()
}
```

---

- From looking at your code, you don't use `time` or `sys` anywhere in this file. Don't import modules if they aren't needed.

Comment: [PEP 396](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/): The module version should be available as a string through the `__version__` attribute.

Comment: The OP's dictionary layout is permitted by PEP-8 (except for the space before the colon, which you've retained). If you're going to give style tips, get them right!

Comment: @200_success Edited post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Edited post.

Comment: `__version__ = "v0.01"` is redundant. Just write `__version__ = "0.01"`.